# Streaming from vlc to html5 video

Tags: streaming, video-streaming, vlc, http-streaming

I'd like the html5 video tag to open a vlc stream, but I don't know if that's even possible.

For now, I'm just trying to play the file from another computer on the network using VLC.

The settings for the server are:

```
me@kaffeesatz:~$ vlc screen:// --screen-left=67 --screen-top=53 --screen-width=800 --screen-height=600 --screen-fps=60 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=theovb=800,scale=1,width=800,height=600,acodec=none}:http{mux=ogg,dst=localhost:8181/graph.ogg}' --ttl=3
```

And when I open the http stream on the same machine, it works fine. The troubles begin when I try playing the stream from another computer. From Chrome, I get the message

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to 192.168.178.23:8181
```

VLC won't connect.

Somehow the stream doesn't seem to make it outside of localhost.

Anyone out there who can help?

Edit: I actually had dst=:8181 already, per a previous question/answer. Setting ttl to 20 didn't magically solve the problem.

Here's the command I'm experiencing the same problem with:

```
me@kaffeesatz:~$ vlc screen:// --screen-left=67 --screen-top=53 --screen-width=800 --screen-height=600 --screen-fps=60 --sout '#transcode{vcodec=theovb=800,scale=1,width=800,height=600,acodec=none}:http{mux=ogg,dst=:8181/graph.ogg}' --ttl=20
```

Comment: Answered over at superuser:
http://superuser.com/questions/412476/vlc-streaming-over-the-network/

Answer (score 0):

You should try port :8080 , like for you own computer go on Chrome and type

```
127.0.0.1:8080/graph.ogg
```

and for your network watch this video that you can see really good picture.

I hope help with something;

Answer (score 0):

You specify in the example to listen on localhost, 'dst=localhost:8181'. That means you cannot access the stream from outside your computer. Try to change it to 'dst=0.0.0.0:8181' or on your external ip address 'dst=192.168.178.23:8181'.